# Insert unique IDs in table from the string with commma separated IDs?

Tags: sql-server

```
Table1
RoomID | UserID | IsDeleted
  1    |  U1    |  0 
  1    |  U2    |  0
  1    |  U3    |  0 

DECLARE @Userids VARCHAR(MAX) = 'U5,U6' , @RoomId int = 3007

INSERT INTO Table1 
(RoomID, UserID, IsDeleted)
SELECT @RoomId, Item, 0 FROM [dbo].[SplitString](@Userids,',')
-- [dbo].[SplitString] is function to get item from comma separated string
```

Now the issue it inserts redundant data.
For Example  `@Userids` is take as `'U5,U7'` then the table results into rows as

```
Table1
RoomID | UserID | IsDeleted
  1    |  U1    |  0 
  1    |  U2    |  0
  1    |  U3    |  0 
  1    |  U5    |  0
  1    |  U6    |  0 
  1    |  U5    |  0
  1    |  U7    |  0
```

My desirable result should be

```
Table1
RoomID | UserID | IsDeleted
  1    |  U1    |  0 
  1    |  U2    |  0
  1    |  U3    |  0 
  1    |  U5    |  0
  1    |  U6    |  0
  1    |  U7    |  0
```

I also tried below query which resulted into 0 row insertion.I mean no row was inserted

```
DECLARE @Userids VARCHAR(MAX) = 'U5,U7' , @BroadCastId int = 3007
 ;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Item FROM [dbo].[SplitString](@Userids,',')
              )
    INSERT INTO Table1 (RoomID, UserID, IsDeleted)
    SELECT @RoomId, Item, 0, GETUTCDATE() FROM CTE
    WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS
         (SELECT RoomID FROM Table1 
                 WHERE RoomID = @RoomId AND IsDeleted = 0 
                 AND UserID IN (SELECT Item FROM CTE))
```

Comment: It seems like your SplitString function might need some work as it appears to return incorrect results.

Comment: @MisterMagoo there is no issue with SplitString function.

Comment: Well, you said you started with 3 rows U1,U2,U3 and tried to insert U5,U7 but ended up inserting 2 x U5, a U6 and a U7, so something is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a direct NOT EXISTS rather than an additional `IN` subquery. I commented out `GETUTCDATE()` since the insert column list has only 3 columns.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Item 
    FROM [dbo].[SplitString](@Userids,',')
    )
INSERT INTO Table1 (RoomID, UserID, IsDeleted)
SELECT @RoomId, Item, 0 --, GETUTCDATE() 
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON
        Table1.RoomID = @RoomId
    AND Table1.IsDeleted = 0 
    AND Table1.UserID = CTE.Item
WHERE Table1.UserID IS NULL;
```

Note that this will not eliminate dups from the source so you'll need to remove dups in from the CTE if that's a possibility.

Comment: Wonderful, it worked!!!

Comment: @HinaKhuman, I forgot to mention about dups in the source list so I added that to my answer.